# Vue JS save incremented number to Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire

I have a simple VueJS app that I'm using with Firebase JSON database. I want to be able to click an arrow to update the "votes" of a comment. (similar to how this website has upvotes). My function runs. But the Vue Model never updates Firebase and so the vote count is lost on refresh. Please reference my CodePen: http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/evowdd/ (Please note that I use Pug and Stylus, to see normal HTML/CSS click the arrow in top right.)

JS:

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    databaseURL: "..."
};
const firebaseapp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebaseapp.database();
const commentsRef = db.ref('test');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        comments: [],
        newComment: {
            name: '',
            comment: '',
            votes: 0
        },
    },
    methods: {
        addComment() {
            commentsRef.push(this.newComment);
            this.newComment.name = '';
            this.newComment.message = '';
            this.newComment.votes = 0;
        },
        vote: function (voteType, comment) {
            if (voteType === "up") {
                comment.votes++
            } else if (voteType === "down") {
                if (comment.votes <= -10) {
                    return;
                }

                comment.votes--;
            }
        },
    },
    firebase: {
        comments: commentsRef
    },

})
```

Comment: The `firebase` property isn't a standard `Vue` option. Are you using [vuefire](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire)? If so, where is it?

Comment: Yes, I am using VueFire. The script tag is located in my CodePen JS settings under resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I believe I've figured it out. Please answer if you have a better method.

Here is the new method with added notes:

```
incrementVote(comment) {
    comment.votes++ //increment the vote count
    const businesschildKey = comment['.key']; //get key of modified comment
    delete comment['.key']; //Firebase doesn't know how to handle them but can use VueFire to get around that.
    this.$firebaseRefs.comments.child(businesschildKey).set(comment) //Updates Firebase record matching key
},
```